# Why is SimpLESS giving syntax error on forward-slash symbol within the background shorthand?

Tags: css, less

Why is the following middle line (line:2) causing syntax error on SimpLESS compiler?
During in-browser compilation, there is no problem via the use of CDNs. However, this doesn't seem to work on Ipad for some reasons.
So I am trying to compile the code before uploading for Ipad use.

```
.box1 {
    background: #000 url("../img/2.jpg") center top / cover;
}
```

Removing the forward slash seems to stop the error, but then it affects the output.

Comment: Specifying `background-size` as a part of shorthand `background` is a relatively recent addition to `background` syntax. So SimpLESS CSS parser is probably just incompatible with this newer `background` syntax. Try to specify `background-size` separately from (after) `background`.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. I dont think I can mark comments as correct / would you like to post the answer for me to accept or is there a way to delete a question?

Comment: Posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying `background-size` as a part of shorthand `background` is a relatively recent addition to `background` syntax.

So SimpLESS CSS parser is probably just incompatible with this newer `background` syntax. Try to specify `background-size` separately from (after) `background`.

```css
.box1 {
    background: #000 url(../img/2.jpg) center top;
    background-size: cover;
}
```